# Event sales_order_invoice_save_after in magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, event-observer

Does in magento 2 exists event similar to event sales_order_invoice_save_after from magento 1?

Or, where should plugin "listen", to get similar functionality?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this event still exists. Just for your knowledge, I would like to share that it will always be fired whenever you made any change in order related data after invoice creation.

So it would be better to use "**sales_order_invoice_pay**" in case you want event to be fired only when first time invoice is created.

Comment: Thanks @Himmat Paliwal it works fine but one issue is there when use 'sales_order_invoice_save_after' i get the invoice increment id but when i use 'sales_order_invoice_pay' i am not get invoice id or increment id. 
can you please help how to get invoice id in event sales_order_invoice_pay.

Comment: It is being triggered from Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice, line number 379, so you can check for the same what value you can get from there. Try by printing print_r($this->getEventObject()->getData());

Comment: i have tried but get only order data not any invoice related data found

Comment: You can get invoice details if you have order id with you.. :) Check a bit on or create a separate issue in case.

Comment: okay thanks @Himmat Paliwal

Comment: @ChandreshChauhan did you get details from order? because its shows null if I am using "sales_order_invoice_pay" event

Comment: @SagarParikhSGR i get only order data not any invoice related data

Answer (score 0):

Check [this link](https://cyrillschumacher.com/magento2-list-of-all-dispatched-events/) for list of all events and observer of Magento-2. I hope this will help you.