# sales_order_save_after event not fired when creating an invoice

Tags: magento2, event-observer

I like the event to be fired when we create an invoice for an order, to get order status **complete**

etc/adminhtml/events.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">

<!-- new code Tarek -->
<event name="sales_order_save_after">
    <observer  name="qbonline_syncOrder_completed" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\Order\Create"/>
</event>
</config>
```

Vendor/Module/Observer/Order/Create.php

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer\Order;

use Magenest\QuickBooksOnline\Observer\AbstractObserver;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface as ObserverInterface;
use Vendor\Module\Model\Synchronization\Order;
use Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface;
use Vendor\Module\Model\Config;
use Vendor\Module\Model\QueueFactory;
use Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory;

/**
  * Class Create
  * @package Magenest\QuickBooksOnline\Observer\Order
*/
class Create extends AbstractObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
/**
 * @var Order
 */
protected $_order;

/**
 * @var OrderFactory
 */
protected $order;

/**
 * Create constructor.
 *
 * @param ManagerInterface $messageManager
 * @param Config $config
 * @param QueueFactory $queueFactory
 * @param Order $order
 * @param OrderFactory $orderFactory
 */
public function __construct(
    ManagerInterface $messageManager,
    Config $config,
    QueueFactory $queueFactory,
    Order $order,
    OrderFactory $orderFactory
) {
    parent::__construct($messageManager, $config, $queueFactory);
    $this->_order = $order;
    $this->order  = $orderFactory;
    $this->type   = 'order';
}

/**
 * Dispatch when Invoice created
 *
 * @param Observer $observer
 */
public function execute(Observer $observer)
{
    if ($this->isConnected() && $this->isConnected() == 1) {
        try {
            /** @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order */
            $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
            if (empty($order)) {
                $orderId = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds()[0];
            } else {
                $orderId = $order->getId();
                if (!empty($order->getBaseTotalInvoiced()))
                    return;
            }
            if ($orderId) {$this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(__('(status: %1) in .', $order->getState()));
                if($order->getState() == 'Complete') {


                    $model  = $this->order->create()->load($orderId);
                    $incrementId = $model->getIncrementId();
                    if ($incrementId && $this->isEnabled()) {
                        if ($this->isImmediatelyMode()) {
                            $qboId = $this->_order->sync($incrementId, true);
                        /**
                         * @var \Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session $adminSession
                         */
                            $adminSession = ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('\Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session');
                            $isAdminPage  = $adminSession->isLoggedIn();
                            if ($qboId and $isAdminPage)
                                $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(__('Successfully updated this Order(Id: %1) in QuickBooksOnline.', $qboId));
                        } else {
                            $this->addToQueue($incrementId);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: did you try this one: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/157519/event-sales-order-invoice-save-after-in-magento-2 ?

Comment: I tried but $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(__('(status: %1) never returns complete status but processing

Answer (score 0):

Magento use 3 areas to manage events :

1. Under `etc/` folder for the both **admin** and **frontend**.
2. Under `etc/frontend` folder for **frontend** area.
3. Under `etc/adminhtml` folder for **admin** area.

So if you are using an **admin event only**, you should use `etc/adminhtml/events.xml` and not `etc/backend/events.xml` as you did

Comment: Sorry it's a typo, i've already put it in adminhtml folder